# How to assert previous exceptions in the stack in PHPUNIT 6.4?

Tags: phpunit

Is there a simple way to expect exceptions which are deeper in the stack of thrown exceptions?

```php
//
//Code:
//
try {
    throw Unauthorized();
} catch(Unauthorized $e) {
    // here I put source exception and wrap it with another one
    throw CommandFailed("message",0,$e);     
}

//
// Test
//

$this->assertException(Unauthorized::class); // this won't work

// the only way I can think of. It works but kind of too wordy.
try { 
    //...code...
} catch(CommandFailed $e) {
    $this->assertEquals(Unauthorized::class, get_class($e->getPrevious()));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code of your test please?

Comment: If you need to find out what an inner exception is, that has been wrapped by another,, that looks to be just what I would do.